# getting null in mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a object in the junit test file. I am getting value in test file

```
public void TestMethod() throws SQLException{

    String projectID    =   "Test";
    Connection connectionMock = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatementMock = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    ResultSet resultSetMock = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    mockStatic(Manager.class);
    Worker  workerMock  =   Mockito.mock(Worker.class);
    mockingDetails(workerMock);
    mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    mock(ResultSet.class);
    when(workerMock.getProjectId())
    .thenReturn(projectID);

    when(Manager.getDatabaseConnection())
    .thenReturn(connectionMock);

    when(connectionMock.prepareStatement(""))
    .thenReturn(preparedStatementMock);

    when(preparedStatementMock.executeQuery())
    .thenReturn(resultSetMock);
    //mockStatic(Manager.class);
    System.out.println("workerMock--------->"+workerMock);
    System.out.println("prepared stmt--------->"+preparedStatementMock);
    assertNotNull(service.getProtocol());
}
```

If I print here I am getting value worker and prepared statement like this value

> "Mock for Worker, hashCode: 853323835"

If I print same in my real method, I am getting null for both worker and prepared statement. I have used annotations

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Manager.class)
```

in the test class

```
public String Method() throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn =   Manager.getDatabaseConnection();
    String  protocol    =   null;
    StringBuilder   qryBuilder  =   new StringBuilder("MyQuery");
    qryBuilder.append("condition = ?");
    System.out.println("worker.getProjectId()------------->"+worker);
    System.out.println("connection------------->"+conn);
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(qryBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println("pst------------->"+pst);
    pst.setString(1, worker.getProjectId());
    try {
        ResultSet rset = pst.executeQuery();
        try {
            while (rset.next()) {
                protocol    =   rset.getString(1);
            }
            rset.close();
        } finally {
            pst.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return protocol;
}
```

Comment: Based o n the posted code, those mocks are not injected into the class that's being tested.

Comment: how to inject those class?. I am new to junit test case

Comment: Through the constructor or a setter of the class to be tested.

Comment: Is `worker` a class variables? where does it come from? If you get to the print `pst` line, then your `conn` object is not null, is that right? Could you post the code of the whole class?

Comment: i have updated with full method. Here worker is a class. From Manager class i am getting Connection, i am not getting in connection

Comment: Where is `worker` declared? and initialized?

Comment: It was declared in Method's class "com.cr.auth.Worker worker = (com.cr.auth.Worker)com.cr.auth.utils.AuthHelper.getUserPrincipal();" I am getting this error only in Junit test run, In normal execution it is working as expected